# Loading a package in each Julia-lang session (avoid retyping 'using xxx' every time)?

Tags: julia

I am using Julia-lang in Ubuntu and have started to use `OhMyREPL` [github repo link](https://github.com/KristofferC/OhMyREPL.jl) which highlights the syntax at the command line in the terminal. I start it with 'using OhMyREPL', but I begin each session with it and want to know how I can have it be loaded (`using`) at the start by default.

In general my question is; *how can I have Julia load a package at the start of each session which I would manually do with 'using XXXX'*.

Comment: put `using OhMyREPL` line in the .juliarc.jl (see package README.md)

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, I used the 'find' command and .juliarc.jl did not come up. I did find a file which contained that file string *juliarc.jl* `# This file should contain site-specific commands to be executed on Julia startup
# Users may store their own personal commands in the user home directory `homedir()`, in a file named .juliarc.jl` , so, I got the `homedir()` function to tell me where to put the file and it works. Could you put this as a general answer so that I can give you credit? and put it as a simple/mini guide for similar start up commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is is to make `using OhMyREPL` be executed by Julia every time on startup when you are running an interactive session (REPL).

The solution is to put the following code

```
if isinteractive()
    using OhMyREPL
end
```

in *.juliarc.jl* file. In this way `OhMyREPL` will be loaded if you start REPL but it will be skipped if you are executing a script.

*.juliarc.jl* is a file that is executed every time Julia is started. It should be created in the directory that is returned by `homedir()` as this is the place where Julia searches for it.

A more advanced solution is to compile `OhMyREPL` into Julia system image as described in https://kristofferc.github.io/OhMyREPL.jl/latest/installation.html#Installation-1. This way REPL will start quicker.